# Best diagram package to draw similar diagrams

Tags: diagrams

I am looking for a way to draw a diagram similar to the figure below which can be used with latex, and look elegant.

[image: Desired diagram]

Comment: You can have a look at `tikz`  {https://texample.net/tikz/examples/tag/circuitikz/.}

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SE... hope `circiuitikz` opt for this....